# Check All Page by Page in Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have a code that displays data in datatables with checkbox and here it is

```
var link = '../../php_try/get_info.php?id='+ nda_id + '&val_dept=' + val_dept + '&val_sect=' + val_sect;
        $('#tbl_user').dataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "order": [],
            "bProcessing": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "iDisplayLength": "All",
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
            "sAjaxSource": link,
            'columnDefs': [{
                'targets': 0,
                'render': function (data, type, row, meta){
                    return '<input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_' + data + '" class="filled-in chk-col-blue chkall" style="display: flex">' +
                           '<label for="md_checkbox_' + data + '"></label>';
                }
            },
            { targets: 0, orderable: false },
            { className: "custom_right", "targets": [1] },
            ],
            "aoColumns": [
                { mData: 'test1' },
                { mData: 'test2' },
                { mData: 'test3' },
                { mData: 'test4' },
                { mData: 'test5' },
                { mData: 'test6' },
                { mData: 'test7' }
            ]
        });
```

Now on this [link](https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/pages/forms/basic-form-elements.html) this is where the checkbox looks like in my table

Now i have a main checkbox and here it is

```
<input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_21" class="filled-in chk-col-blue">
<label for="md_checkbox_21">Check All</label>
```

and my code for selecting all checkbox in datatables is this

```
/* Check all sub checkbox if main checkbox is checked */
$("#md_checkbox_21").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('.chkall').prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $('.chkall').prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

actually its working the problem is the other checkbox on the hidden page are not checked. my question is how can i check all checkbox including on those other pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in draw event handler.

```
DTable.on('draw', function () {
    if($('#md_checkbox_21').is(':checked') == true){
        $('.chkall').prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

For the above code to work.

Change:

```
$('#tbl_user').dataTable({
```

To:

```
var DTable = $('#tbl_user').dataTable({
```

Comment: i dont know if i can run it because my data is based on database

Comment: It can run even if it's based on database.